# U-SQL Python extension: very slow performance

Tags: python, u-sql

I'm doing something seemingly trivial that takes much longer than I would expect it to. I'm loading a 70MB file, running it through a reducer which calls a Python script that does not modify the data, and writing the data back to a new file.

It takes 42 minutes when I run it through the Python script, it takes less than one minute (including compilation) if I don't.

I'm trying to understand:

- What am I doing wrong?
- What is going on underneath the hood that takes so long?

I store the input and output files on Azure Data Lake Store. I'm using parallelism 1, a TSV input file of about 70MB (2000 rows, 2 columns). I'm just passing the data through. It takes 42 minutes until the job finishes.

I generated the test input data with this Python script:

```
import base64

# create a roughly 70MB TSV file with 2000 rows and 2 columns: ID (integer) and roughly 30KB data (string)
fo = open('testinput.tsv', 'wb')
for i in range(2000):
    fo.write(str(i).encode() + b'\t' + base64.b85encode(bytearray(os.urandom(30000))) + b'\n')
fo.close()
```

This is the U-SQL script I use:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [ExtPython];

DECLARE @myScript = @"
def usqlml_main(df):
    return df
";

@step1 = 
 EXTRACT 
    col1 string,
    col2 string
 FROM "/test/testinput.tsv" USING Extractors.Tsv();;

@step2 =
 REDUCE @ncsx_files ON col1
 PRODUCE col1 string, col2 string
 USING new Extension.Python.Reducer(pyScript:@myScript);

OUTPUT @step2
 TO "/test/testoutput.csv"
 USING Outputters.Tsv(outputHeader: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

I have a 116 mb csv file I want to read in (and then do stuff). When trying to read in the file and do nothing in the python script it times out after 5 hours, I even tried reducing the file to 9,28 mb it also times out after 5 hours.

However, when reduced to 1,32 mb the job finishes after 16 mins. (With results as expected).

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [ExtPython];

DECLARE @myScript = @"
def usqlml_main(df):
    return df
";

@train = 
    EXTRACT txt string,
            casegroup string
    FROM "/test/t.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();
@train =
    SELECT *,
        1 AS Order
    FROM @train
ORDER BY Order
FETCH 10000;

@train =
    SELECT txt,
        casegroup
    FROM @train;  // 1000 rows: 16 mins, 10000 rows: times out at 5 hours.

@m  =
    REDUCE @train ON txt, casegroup
    PRODUCE txt string, casegroup string
    USING new Extension.Python.Reducer(pyScript:@myScript);

OUTPUT @m
TO "/test/t_res.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Comment: Did you guys found the solution ?

Comment: Nope. We've started using databricks whenever we need/want to use python code. You can connect it nicely with datafactory and so on, works well for us.

Answer (score 1):

`REDUCE @ROWSET ALL`

If you don't reduce on ALL, it will invoke the python function per row.

If you want to use parallelism, you could create temporary groups to reduce on.